# Unable to install plugins

Tags: plugins, installation

I downloaded a wiziapp plugin. Then I tried to install it on WordPress. It shows "file size exceed maximum in php.ini"

How to install this plugin anyone help me

Comment: What is the size of the plugin?

Comment: It's size is 2.41 MB

Comment: And What is the value of upload_max_filesize in php.ini?

Comment: Where can i find this.. I'm new to php

Comment: Upload a new phpinfo.php file on the root directory of your website and it should contain <?php phpinfo(); ?> then visit file URL http://www.your-domain.com/phpinfo.php on browser and search for this key I asked.

Comment: Upload limit can also be modified using `.htaccess` file. [Check this link](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/increasing-upload-max-file-size-in-phpini)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to unzip it on your local computer and use an FTP software to upload it to the wp-content/plugins directory.